# How to configure Postfix with transport_maps and randmap?

Tags: postfix-mta

I'm currently using a postfix server with 4 IP (relay1, relay2, relay 3, relay4) for outgoing emails
I'm using transport_maps to define for each email domain (outlook.fr, orange.fr ...) the relay to use
It works well but I just realized that my postfix active queue was full, having mostly orange.fr emails, it gets quickly full as only 1 relay is defined to send emails for that domain.

What I'm trying to do is to load balance orange.fr emails between the 4 IP while keeping transport_maps to manage other email domains
I tried using `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps =  randmap:{relay1,relay2,relay3,relay4}` for load balancing and it works but for all domains.

In postfix release notes a solution seems given but I cannot have it to work: http://postfix.cs.utah.edu/source/official/postfix-3.0.0-RC1.RELEASE_NOTES

```
/etc/postfix/main.cf:
    transport_maps = 
        # Deliver my own domain as usual.
        hash:/etc/postfix/transport 
        # Deliver other domains via randomly-selected relayhosts
        randmap:{smtp:smtp0.example.com, smtp:smtp1.example.com}
```

From my understanding postfix should read first transport_maps and if the domain is not found send using randmap. But in this case only randmap is working.

Summary:

If I use only transport file = emails are sent to specific relays but can't have one or more relays for a given domain
If I use only randmap = emails are sent using the 4 IP but i cant specify relays for specific domains
If I use transport and randmap = transport file seems ignored, only randmap is effective

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you configured your master.cf or your server so I'll just share my experience

My server has 5 IP (let's call them int1-int5)

First I configured these as interfaces in my master.cf

Example with int1

```
int1        unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
     -o smtp_helo_name=int1.domain.com
     -o syslog_name=postfix-int1
     -o smtp_bind_address=x.x.x.x
```

My main.cf :

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport randmap:{int1,int2,int3,int4,int5}

smtp_connection_cache_on_demand = no

transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
```

`sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = randmap:{int1,int2,int3,int4,int5}` : the load balancing

`sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport` : specific relay for senders (mail from)

`transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport` : specific relay for recipients (mail to)

/etc/postfix/sender_transport or hash:/etc/postfix/transport example :

```
user@domain1.com int5:
domain2.com int5:
```